# How to create the folder in a remote place using C#

Tags: c#, server

How can I create a folder and programmatically access it on a server using C#?

I have used this code:

```
string path = @"\\MyIP\C$\NEWFOLDER";

try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Using above code, I can create a folder on my local machine only!

When I try to create a folder on the server machine, I get this exception:

> The user name or password is incorrect

Comment: Can You create it using File Explorer and your account?

Answer (score 0):

You need do some configurations on your server. This is because local pc -> server need permission. You need to allow [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) have the permission to create a folder on your server.

- *[You receive a "logon failure: unknown user name or bad" error message while accessing remote security-enhanced resources from an ASP.NET application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/842789)*
- *[Homegroup Problem - Logon failure; unknown user name or bad password](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/homegroup-problem-logon-failure-unknown-user-name/41699402-e7ea-4674-854e-17dacb28a793)*

Answer (score 0):

It should work as long as you can access the folder from source (where your program is running). To check it, open file explorer in source machine and type \\targetMachineIp\C$\, if you can reach there and can create a folder that means only problem is in user permissions under which your program is running, try to run it under your user account.